# Python skipping my if and else statement in a for loop, but the for loop is running

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, user-interface

Well im still learning and im now into pyqt5 designer but i have a problem with a for and if statement where python dont do neither of the else or if, i use the print (empleados[i]["Nombre"]), to check if the else is running but none of the if or else run

```
        for i in range(0,len(empleados)):
            print(empleados[i]["Numero"])
            if self.ui.num.text() == empleados[i]["Numero"]:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self,"Advertencia","No se pueden registrar dos numeros de empleado iguales")    
            else:
                
                empleados.append({"Nombre":self.ui.nom.text(),
                                  "Numero":self.ui.num.text(),
                                  "Salario":self.ui.salario.text(),
                                  "Dep":self.ui.dep.currentText(),
                                  "FechaC":self.ui.dateC.date(),
                                  "FechaN":self.ui.dateN.date()})
                print (empleados[i]["Nombre"])
                break
```

Comment: It seems impossible to me that none of the conditionals run. You might be missing something. My assumption is that the first condition is successfully running but you are missing something. Did you try a print line under it as well?

Comment: The second line under the for is printing, but nothing more is printing

Comment: I think It might have been because your emplados variable was initally empty? Btw I know your problem has been solved but I am trying to understand why this didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the intent to append a new element to `empleados` if and only if there isn't any with a matching `Numero`?  If so I think this'll do the trick:

```
if any(e["Numero"] == self.ui.num.text() for e in empleados):
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
        self,
        "Advertencia",
        "No se pueden registrar dos numeros de empleado iguales"
    )
else:
    empleados.append({
        "Nombre":self.ui.nom.text(),
        "Numero":self.ui.num.text(),
        "Salario":self.ui.salario.text(),
        "Dep":self.ui.dep.currentText(),
        "FechaC":self.ui.dateC.date(),
        "FechaN":self.ui.dateN.date()
    })
```

In general, modifying a list as you're iterating over it doesn't work well, but in this case I don't think you want to do the append inside the loop anyway, since you only want to append one element.

If `Numero` is unique, you might consider making `empleados` a dictionary keyed on that field, e.g.:

```
emp_by_num = {e["Numero"]: e for e in empleados}
```

so that you can do quick checks with `in` rather than having to use `any`:

```
if self.ui.num.text() in emp_by_num:
```

Comment: Yes, i only want to append in the list when empleados dont have already a Numero equal to the inserted, and thanks it work very good :)